# Can't grant permissions for MS Asure graph API client app to fetch data about ManagedDevices. How to overcome?

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, adal, intune

I have registered a new app, copied `tenant`, `client_id`, and `client_secret`. I can access https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 with `Bearer`, and `access token` - works fine. But I can't get anything else. Tried to grant scopes to this app - w/o luck.[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pprint
import adal
import requests

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint

tenant = "<>"
client_id = "<>"
client_secret = "<>"

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

# Use this for Client Credentials
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    RESOURCE,
    client_id,
    client_secret
)

graph_api_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0{0}'
# /me only works with ROPC, for Client Credentials you'll need /<UsersObjectId/
request_url = graph_api_endpoint.format('/Management/managedDevices')
#request_url = graph_api_endpoint.format('/me')
headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token["accessToken"]),
'Accept' : 'application/json',
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = headers)
pp(response.json())
```

Here is the error from HTTP reply from the API

```
{   'error': {   'code': 'UnknownError',
                 'innerError': {   'date': '2020-03-15T06:57:54',
                                   'request-id': 'f011ca02-f8c6-4bcb-90a2-9decbed2cfce'},
                 'message': '{"ErrorCode":"Unauthorized","Message":"{\\r\\n  '
                            '\\"_version\\": 3,\\r\\n  \\"Message\\": \\"An '
                            'error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer '
                            'support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - '
                            'Activity ID: f011ca02-f8c6-4bcb-90a2-9decbed2cfce '
                            '- Url: '
                            'https://fef.amsua0402.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices?api-version=2018-05-24\\",\\r\\n  '
                            '\\"CustomApiErrorPhrase\\": \\"\\",\\r\\n  '
                            '\\"RetryAfter\\": null,\\r\\n  '
                            '\\"ErrorSourceService\\": \\"\\",\\r\\n  '
                            '\\"HttpHeaders\\": '
                            '\\"{\\\\\\"WWW-Authenticate\\\\\\":\\\\\\"Bearer '
                            'realm=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"urn:intune:service,c3998d6e-2e37-4c56-87b5-7b444ee1cb26,f0f3c450-59bf-4f0d-b1b2-0ef84ddfe3c7\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\"}\\"\\r\\n}","Target":null,"Details":null,"InnerError":null,"InstanceAnnotations":[]}'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using client credential flow which request an access token with application permissions.
However, managed device apis are not supported with application permissions.

[image]

Reference:

[Delegated permissions and Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types)

Comment: Is it possible to use delegated permissions type for the console app / ETL app without WEB UI and a possibility to auth User via it?

Comment: @greggyNapalm You can try ROPC flow, but Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc